# Gap on right of website

Tags: html, css

When my site loads the view is correct but if you scroll right there is a gap. All div's have 100% width set and no padding on right... I went through each element to putting display:none trying to single the problamatic element but this didn't help either. A test version of the site is available at www.emma-cooper.co.uk

Comment: You should provide the relevant code in the question. It is unreasonable to expect the community to go to your website and browse all of the code to trouble shoot your problem.

Comment: Apply `overflow-x: hidden` to `body`.

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take `width:100%;` out of the `#logo` CSS definition, and the right and left padding off the 
`div#hmenu` definition (make it `padding:0.8em 0;`)

Comment: Worked a treat, thank you!